# Refresh a pageBlockTable inside the tab using button

Tags: visualforce, refresh, tabpanel

My visual page having a pageBlockTable inside a tab. Also there is a button inside the same tab named Refresh. I need to refresh the pageBlockTable using the refresh button. The following code is not working

**Code:**

```
<apex:tab label="Info" name="info" id="info">
    <apex:form id="tabForm1">
        <apex:commandbutton value="Refresh" reRender="tabForm1"/>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!getAllInfo}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:tab>
```

Comment: where is tabForm2 ?

Comment: @Ratan Sorry typo. That is tabForm1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the changed code below:

**Code:**

```
<apex:tab label="Info" name="info" id="info">
    <apex:form id="tabForm1">
        <apex:commandbutton value="Refresh" reRender="pgTbl0"/> <!-- CHANGED HERE -->
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!getAllInfo}" var="a" id="pgTbl0"> <!-- AND HERE -->
            <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:form>
</apex:tab>
```

If this doesn't work, wrap the table in an outputPanel and rerender the outputPanel instead.

Comment: @SANN3 happy to help! :)